What are differences between PBEWithHmacSHA256 and HmacPBESHA256
On the page of Mac Algorithms, there are the following entries.

PBEWith\<mac>, e.g. PBEWithHmacSHA256
HmacPBESHA256

What are differences between them?

The page you linked to has references for everything.

But make sure you read the erratum for rfc7292 (or the original RSALabs doc if you find it) because it affects the key derivation in B.2 which is used in B.4 (B.5 in original)
